# What Schema.org properties for video search results?

Tags: schema.org

I'm making a website where you can search videos on. Every search returns about 50 links to a video player incl. thumbnail, name, duration, rating, actors, company that made it and a text saying "Video Results For {{QUERY}}" on the top.

I've looked at the hierarchy of Schema.org but I've no idea what properties to use as well as how to define so much information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`SearchResultsPage` type](http://schema.org/SearchResultsPage) for the webpage, the [`ItemList` type](http://schema.org/ItemList) for the result list, and the [`VideoObject` type](http://schema.org/VideoObject) for each result.

To relate the `ItemList` to the `SearchResultsPage`, you could use the [`mainEntity` property](http://schema.org/mainEntity), and to relate the `VideoObject` items to the `ItemList`, the [`itemListElement` property](http://schema.org/itemListElement).

In RDFa, this could look like:

```html
<body typeof="schema:SearchResultsPage">
  <section property="schema:mainEntity" typeof="schema:ItemList">
    <article property="schema:itemListElement" typeof="schema:VideoObject"></article>
    <article property="schema:itemListElement" typeof="schema:VideoObject"></article>
    <article property="schema:itemListElement" typeof="schema:VideoObject"></article>
  </section>
</body>
```

If the search results are ordered/ranked, you might want to use [`ListItem`](http://schema.org/ListItem) and give its [`position`](http://schema.org/position):

```html
<body typeof="schema:SearchResultsPage">
  <section property="schema:mainEntity" typeof="schema:ItemList">
    <article property="schema:itemListElement" typeof="schema:ListItem">
      <meta property="schema:position" content="1">
      <div property="schema:item" typeof="schema:VideoObject"></div>
    </article>
    <article property="schema:itemListElement" typeof="schema:ListItem">
      <meta property="schema:position" content="2">
      <div property="schema:item" typeof="schema:VideoObject"></div>
    </article>
    <article property="schema:itemListElement" typeof="schema:ListItem">
      <meta property="schema:position" content="3">
      <div property="schema:item" typeof="schema:VideoObject"></div>
    </article>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Google's recommendation which you can see in the follow link:
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/videosearch/schema

The best practice for videos is using the VideoObject itemtype.
As you can see - there are indeed properties like actor, creator (Inherits from CreativeWork), Rating (aggregateRating), thumbnail and many many more.

I love the using of microdata tags it improves your site's SEO dramatically.

**UPDATE**: After author clarification - for search result - also for videos (see an example in vimeo search result) - you should use the [ItemList](https://schema.org/ItemList) Item type.
Good luck!

Comment: That would be the actual video object not the results that go to a video (object) player.

Comment: Updated my answer according to your clarification.