# Schema.org for search results page

Tags: schema.org, google-sitelink-searchbox

I implemented a Google Sitelinks Searchbox on my home page.
I've checked https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox and it doesn't mention which format I should use for the results page.

Which Schema.org type can be used for my own SERPs? Should I use an XML sitemap, JSON-LD, Microdata?

Comment: This feature is for showing your search field in Google Search. Your site’s search results aren’t involved.

Comment: I know that! I just want to know how should I format the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`SearchResultsPage`](https://schema.org/SearchResultsPage) type.

Each result could be a [`WebPage`](https://schema.org/WebPage) (or a more specific type, like [`ItemPage`](https://schema.org/ItemPage) if it applies).

To connect the `SearchResultsPage` with the `WebPage` results, you can use the [`mainEntity`](https://schema.org/mainEntity) property with an [`ItemList`](https://schema.org/ItemList) value. You can find [RDFa examples in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30527119/1591669).